# call to angularjs controller fail first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project in which I have used mvc,bootstrap and angularjs.Everything is working fine,but the problem I am facing is that I don't get data on first call but gets data on second click.Suppose I have a link MyIssues-then if first time I click on this link only my static shared view appears and rest portion appears empty but on second click eveything works fine.I am not getting where is the error,my console is showing no error.Actually I tried many things and found that my angular controllers are loaded but my controllers are not called on first click.

Following are the controllers I am using
BaseController.js

```
  var userImagePath;
alert('test');
var app = angular.module('Trackue', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ng.deviceDetector', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('Trackue').filter('fromNow', function () {
alert('common');
return function (date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
};
});
  alert('base');
 var baseController = function ($scope, $http) {
alert('base pic');
$scope.UnreadNotificationCount = 0;
$scope.ProfileImagePath = "";
$scope.UnseenNotifications = [];
$scope.myIssueCount = 0;
//Loading User Profile Image
$scope.GetUserProfilePic = function () {
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/Home' + '/GetUserImage/';
    $http.post(url, []).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data != '') {
            $scope.ProfileImagePath = JSON.parse(data);
            userImagePath = $scope.ProfileImagePath;
        } else {
            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
        }
    });
};
$scope.GetUserProfilePic();

$scope.GetUnseenUserNotification = function () {
    //        var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/Home' + '/GetUserNotifications/';
    //        $http.post(url, []).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //            if (data) {
    //                //alert(data);
    //                $scope.UnreadNotificationCount = data.length;
    //                $scope.UnseenNotifications = data;
    //            } else {
    //                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
    //            }
    //        });
};
$scope.GetUnseenUserNotification();

$scope.GetMyIssueCount = function () {
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/Issues' + '/GetMyIssueCount/';
    $http.post(url, []).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data) {
            $scope.myIssueCount = data;
        } else {
            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
        }
    });
};
$scope.GetMyIssueCount();
};
```

MyIssuesController.js

```
alert("my issues");
 var myIssuesController = function ($scope, $sce, $http, cfpLoadingBar, deviceDetector, $filter, $modal, $log) {
alert("start");
$("#navMyIssues").addClass("active");
$scope.issueCommnets = null;
$scope.showComments = false;
   $scope.Issues = [];
 $scope.dateFormat = 'dd-MMM-yyyy';
$scope.dateTimeFormat = 'dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a';
$scope.selectedIssue = null;
$scope.statusName = null;
$scope.ProjectDetails = [];
$scope.selectedProject = null;
$scope.isVisible = false;
$scope.isVisibleReply = false;
$scope.notifiedMembers = null;
$scope.defaultProfileImagePath = "";
$scope.pendingIssueCount = 0;
$scope.inprogressIssueCount = 0;
$scope.limitationIssueCount = 0;
$scope.needsresearchIssueCount = 0;
$scope.intestingIssueCount = 0;
//$scope.issueCount = -1;
$scope.issuesLoaded = false;
$scope.issueDetailsLoaded = false;
$scope.modalHeader;
$scope.options;
var selectedTab;
var blob;

 //custom search
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

$scope.searchIssue = function (item) {
    if (!$scope.query) return true;
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + escapeRegExp($scope.query), 'i');
    var itemid;
    if ($scope.query.indexOf("-") > -1) {
        itemid = item.FullId;
    } else {
        itemid = item.FullId.replace("-", "");
    }
    var result = regex.test(itemid);
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return regex.test(item.Title);
    }
};

$scope.GetDefaultProfilePic = function () {
    alert("1");
    if ($scope.defaultProfileImagePath == "") {
        var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/Issues' + '/GetDefaultUserProfileImage/';
        $http.post(url, []).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data != '' || data.length == 0) {
                $scope.Projects = data;
                if (data != '' || data.length == 0) {
                    $scope.defaultProfileImagePath = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.fromJson(data));
                } else {
                    $scope.defaultProfileImagePath = "";
                }
            } else {
                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
            }
        });
    }
};
$scope.GetDefaultProfilePic();
 }
```

Comment: Please use a jsfiddle to get formatted and runnable code..

Comment: Have you added the controllers to your module?

Comment: yes,it works fine if I open my links in new tab and also works fine on second click...just having problem on first time click

Comment: I my case I am using it in Laravel, and my env() function was not working for first time.